# MooFlow image size

Tags: javascript, image, frameworks, mootools, size

I'm a n00b when talking about MooFlow and MooTools. I need to display some high res images(like 1000x600), however something is going wrong. Check out a screenshot:

http://twitpic.com/3eq15w

I need to display the images in a bigger size. It would be fine if I could only display 800x400 or something like that, but people must be able to see the images decently. Does anyone know a good way to solve that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give more details. Is there a bug, or does the library just not do what you want it to do?

Comment: I'd like to be able to make the images be displayed bigger. I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: what's the real size of the image?

Comment: The images are 793x480 and 1024x662. It would be fine to me to use another plugin(it can be jQuery and MooTools), but it must be good.

Comment: By bigger, do you mean zoomed in more? What is the tool doing, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Are you seeing the same problem in all browsers, or is it browser specific?

Comment: It's all the same in Firefox and Safari(these are the 2 browsers I'm targeting. I expected the pics to show bigger than they actually show. I noticed that it happens when the width is big. As you may see on the screenshot I've posted, it's displaying very small images when they are much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

To get your images popping up in their full glory you'll need to implement some kind of lightbox script, attached to the click event of each image.  Check out some available [mootools  lightbox scripts](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-mootools-lightbox-scripts).

If you want to display the images in a size which is bigger than the users browser resolution, you'll need to either open a new page (and not use a lightbox script) or ensure the lightbox script you use can handle iframes.  This iframe solution will give your lightbox scroll bars so the user can access the whole image.

My preferred lightbox solution is shadowbox as it can handle lots of media types and provides iframe support.